# Scala eclipse IDE not recognizing package import statements

Tags: eclipse, scala, scalatra, spp

I'm trying to build a simple chat scalatra file as an exercise, and was having some frustrating packaging problems. (I'm using Eclipse Indigo's Scala IDE)

This is my file hierarchy:

1. ScalaChat (project folder)

   - src/main/scala

     - (default)
     - com.example.chat

       - ChatController.scala  <--

   . .
   .

   - src/main/webapp/WEB_INF/view/pages

     - show.ssp <--

Chat.controller is packaged with:

```
package com.example.chat
```

and contains the case class:

```
case class Page(slug: String, title: String, summary: String, body: String)
```

and yet, when show.ssp calls:

```
<%@ import val page: com.example.chat.Page %>
```

sbt consistently gives the error:

```
type Page is not a member of package com.example.chat
```

I'm sort of at my wits end.  I can't see an error in the way I'm packaging, but I can't think of what else is wrong with the code.  Could this be a problem with the Scala IDE?

Comment: Have you tried updating to a newer version?  Kepler just came out.

Comment: What does your sbt build file look like?

Comment: Updating seems to have solved the problem, thanks nitind.  It seems early versions of Scala's Eclipse can be buggy, which is frustrating